# How can I maintain consistency between my linux shell environment and macos using homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to develop interoperability in my shell configuration between *nix and macos. Various scripts and configurations I use depend on gnu utilities and assume they are in the PATH. To that end, I have installed many GNU command line tools with homebrew and the `--with-default-names` switch where possible and appropriate.

However, the binutils and coreutils packages do not ship with a `--with-default-names` switch in the homebrew formula. To achieve parity in the interactive shell, I can simply make aliases, e.g. `alias dircolors='gdircolors'`.  However, a script is executed in a subshell and consequently does not inherit aliases, and so `dircolors` will fail. Testing for the presence of a dependency does not work either, as in the case of `chown` the built-in package will be used (and fail if I use features that are not present in the macos distribution).

At this point, I'm considering creating a bundle of shell scripts that test for the presence of the gnu version of the utility and execute it if found, and placing them in the PATH, like so:

```
$ cat chmod
if command -v gchmod > /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; then
  gchmod "$@"
else
  chmod "$@"
fi
```

This seems awfully unwieldy and I'd rather avoid it if possible, though.

Aside from building binutils and coreutils myself, what other solutions are possible?